# How to search for models using find method that has been overwritten?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I'm using loopback.io and I have redefined the `.find` method of a model in order to implement my custom logic

```
var find = Meal.find;
Meal.find = function (filter, cb) {

  _getCurrentUser(function (id) {

    if (id) {

    } else {
      cb(null, []);
    }

    return find.apply(this, arguments);
  });
}
```

But now how can I search through instances since my `.find` method doesn't not do its old plain job?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to rename your custom find method so that you can have access to both.

Comment: @amuramoto this is not working, because it needs to have the same name in ordered to be called from the framework

Answer (score 0):

If you need your custom logic to execute when LoopBack calls find() (or if you need to customize any of the built-in methods), you should use a remote hook instead of overwriting the built-in find(). For example this will execute when find() is called by the framework, and then continue on to execute find():

```
module.exports = function(Meal) {
  Car.beforeRemote('find', function(context, unused, next) {
    //you custom logic here
    next();
  });      
}
```

If you need it to happen after, there's the `afterRemote` hook.